# .net mvc Windows authentication to multiple ad domains

Tags: asp.net-mvc, active-directory

I have an application that needs users  to authenticate from two domains: A and B.
The application is an .net MVC 5 application using windows authentication

It is established one-way trust between the domains, and I have tested the trust, so it should be all good. The application is deployed on domain A, so I have noe problem with users from that domain.

However, when I try to log on from the other domain, I am promted with a logon-box and a 401 error message.

Are there any configuration steps I am missing to get the solution working?

Comment: Do users on Domain B have access to the app on Domain A? Edit: Also, have you confirmed your webconfig settings are correct? Is this IIS?

Comment: No, the users on domain B gets the 401 response when trying the app.
The only thing I have configured in the web.config is to set <authentication mode="Windows"/>
And yes, it is IIS

Comment: Sounds like AD permission issue.

Comment: The solution was quite embarrassing... I just had to give read-access to everyone on the application folder

Comment: those are the best solutions..The ones that are easy.